# Modify Electron Browser Window Options Without Recreating Window?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an "always on top" toggle in my app. I was wondering if there was a way to apply this setting without closing and recreating the window.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `win.setAlwaysOnTop(!win.isAlwaysOnTop())`

[Ref.](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winsetalwaysontopflag-level-relativelevel)